# Php to java- treeview program

Tags: java, php

Iam new to java and iam trying a program that prints multilevel menu. By searching, i got a program in php but i need to rewrite that php code in java. Can anyone help me in this?
PHP program

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$dbname = "crudangularjs";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM menus";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

//iterate on results row and create new index array of data
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res) ) {
$data[] = $row;
}
$itemsByReference = array();


// Build array of item references:
foreach($data as $key => $item) {

$itemsByReference[$item['id']] = $item;
///echo ('<pre>');
    //print_r($itemsByReference[$item['id']]);
// Children array:
$itemsByReference[$item['id']]['nodes'] = array();
// Empty data class (so that json_encode adds "data: {}" )
//$itemsByReference[$item['id']]['data'] = new StdClass();
}
// Set items as children of the relevant parent item.
foreach($data as $key => $item)
if($item['parent'] != '0' && isset($itemsByReference[$item['parent']]))
$itemsByReference [$item['parent']]['nodes'][] = $item;
// Remove items that were added to parents elsewhere:
foreach($data as $key => $item) {
if($item['parent'] && isset($itemsByReference[$item['parent']]))
unset($data[$key]);
}
// Encode:
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

This code i tried to convert into java program as follows

```
Class.forName(driverName);
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            Statement st=conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM menus");
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            while(rs.next()){
                //System.out.println(rs.getString("label"));
                list.add(rs.getString("id"));
                list.add(rs.getString("label"));
                list.add(rs.getString("link"));
                list.add(rs.getString("parent"));
            }
            //int index = 0;
            for (String item : list) {
                System.out.println(item);
            }
```

Comment: Is this code in a webapp? are you using a servlet container?

Comment: yes this code is in webapp.

Comment: in a tomcat server?

Comment: Yes it is in tomcat server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add a datasource in conf/server.xml of your tomcat installation:

```
...
<GlobalNamingResources>
    ...
    <Resource auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            name="jdbc/mydb"
            driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/crudangularjs"
            maxActive="10"
            maxIdle="5"
            validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            testOnBorrow="true"
            testWhileIdle="true"
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="10000"
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="60000"
            username="root"
            password=""/>
</GlobalNamingResources>
....
```

Then, declare a link in the META-INF/context.xml of your webapp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/myapp">
    <ResourceLink global="jdbc/mydb" name="jdbc/mydb"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</Context>
```

You can now get a connection to the database in your java code by doing:

```
Connection openConnection() {
    Context context = new InitialContext();    
    return (Connection)context.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/mydb");
}
```

Now you will want to declare a class to represent a menu item:

```
public class MenuItem {
    private String id;
    private String label;
    private String link;
    private MenuItem parent;
    private final List<MenuItem> children = new ArrayList<>();

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public MenuItem getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(MenuItem parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public List<MenuItem> getChildren() {
        return new ArrayList<>(children);
    }

    public void addChild(MenuItem child) {
        children.add(child);
    }
}
```

Now, below the code that would read all the items and link them according to the `parent` column of the database. We must do this in two passes, because an item may reference another one that we have not yet read; so we put the items in a `Map` where the key is the `id`, and we put the `parent` link in another map:

```
Map<String,MenuItem> items = new HashMap<>();
Map<String,String> parentMap = new HashMap<>();
// Fill the maps
try (Connection cnt = openConnection();
        PreparedStatement stmt = cnt.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM menus");
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
    while (rs.next()) {
        MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
        item.setId(rs.getString("id"));
        item.setLabel(rs.getString("label"));
        item.setLink(rs.getString("link"));
        items.put(item.getId(), item);
        String parent = rs.getString("parent");
        if (parent != null && !parent.equals("0")) {
            parentMap.put(item.getId(), parent);
        }
    }
}
// Resolve the hierarchy
for (Map.Entry<String,String> e: parentMap.entrySet()) {
    MenuItem item = items.get(e.getKey());
    String parentId = e.getValue();
    MenuItem parent = items.get(parentId);
    item.setParent(parent);
    if (parent != null) {
        parent.addChild(item);
    }
}
// Remove all items that have a parent
for (String id: parentMap.keySet()) {
    items.remove(id);
}
```

UPDATE

Note that if you want to preserve the order of the items, you can use `LinkedHashMap`s instead of `HashMap`.

Comment: Thank you Very much for your patience. 
When i try to convert "items" in to json. it is showing java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: @user2121148 if your generating json, you shouldn't generate both the `parent` and the `children`. If you don't need the link to the parent, you can remove the field or declare it as `transient`.

Comment: But i need to send  both parent and children response as json to frontend so that it will be appear as treeview.

Comment: @user2121148 not possible: JSON cannot reference other objects.

Comment: @user2121148 but you can send the id of the parent.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try if any other way to do this, Please let me know if you know any other way. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're going to want a data mapping object of some sort. Something like

```
...
}

public class listItem {
    String id;
    String label;
    String link;
    String parent;
    public listItem(String id, String label, String link, String parent) {
    ...
    public String getId() {
    ...
    public String setLabel(String label) {
    ...
 }
```

Then your code block would look more like:

```
Class.forName(driverName);
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
Statement st=conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM menus");
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
List<listItem> list = new ArrayList<>();
while(rs.next()){
    list.add(new listItem(rs.getString("id"),rs.getString("label"),rs.getString("link"), rs.getString("parent"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. iam looking for the code which is in foreach loops. Can you please advise me or let me know how to write that logic in java